# How to prevent wallpaper compression in Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, compression, desktop-customization

I'm running Windows 10 October Update and Windows 10 reduces my wallpaper quality every time!

I already followed this step:

1. Open Registry Editor
2. Go to **HKCU\Control Panel\Desktop**
3. Create an DWORD value named JPEGImportQuality.
4. Set it as **decimal** and the value to **100**

But my wallpaper quality still gets reduced.

For example here is a test that I made to ensure that the setting still works.

The following is the original image made in MSPaint (2MB):

http://www.mediafire.com/convkey/153d/5yingeet7scwslwzg.jpg?size_id=7

The next image shows the compressed image by Windows (85kb):

http://www.mediafire.com/convkey/6816/kniw41nx21x7wzjzg.jpg

Every time when I set the wallpaper, it reduces the quality. How can i solve this in the new Windows 10 update?

Comment: JPEG is designed for images with gradients, like photos.  The compression messes up low-color artwork and text.  I don't know if only jpg images can be used for wallpaper, but an alternate solution would be to see if you can use an image with lossless compression.  For example, try saving the original image as a gif.

Comment: `2.188kb` is not less than `85kb`. What am I missing?

Answer (score 2):

Windows saves the compressed version of the background image to the following directory:

```
C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Themes
```

It's stored there as a file named `TranscodedWallpaper` that has no file extension.

Rename the `TranscodedWallpaper` file to something like `TranscodedWallpaper_old`,
just in case, and replace it by the original image, also
renamed to `TranscodedWallpaper` with no file extension.

The image should now display with no degradation.

Comment: I moved the full quality image now. What should i do next for the changes to take effect?

Comment: Logoff/on or reboot.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue.
Here's the solution:

1. **Go to folder options** (Open documents, go to "View" on the ribbon and select "Options" on the right)
2. Go to the **"View" tab**
3. **Uncheck** the "Hide extensions for known file types" option.

The only thing left to do now is rename your `.jpg` image to `.jpeg`.
Right click on the Image and set it as background.

For some reason, if the image isn't `.jpeg` (and it's `.jpg`) it gets compressed.

Answer (score 1):

When you're setting a wallpaper, you **don't wanna** set it from the Windows Photo Viewer.
Instead, set it directly from the image file, right click and choose **Set as desktop background**.
I've made a comparison and here is the result:[image]

Answer (score 0):

Another possibly safest solution is to save the image as PNG and set it as the background. As of today, Windows 10 did not compress the PNG images I tried to set as backgrounds. I think the compression happens only with JPG images(thus the registry name JPEGImportQuality, maybe).